# Limiting the number of items returned by a request?

Tags: support, api, limits, paging

How can I limit the amount of items returned to me when performing an API call?

I only want the top 10 most commonly used tags, by default I'm sent back 30. EG:

```
api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow
```

Yields:

```
[items] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [has_synonyms] => 1
            [is_moderator_only] => 
            [is_required] => 
            [count] => 804152
            [name] => java
        )
    [1] => Array ( 
            [has_synonyms] => 1
            [is_moderator_only] => 
            [is_required] => 
            [count] => 793946
            [name] => javascript
        )
    ... ...
    [29] => Array (
            [has_synonyms] => false
            [is_moderator_only] => false
            [is_required] => false
            [count] => 90377
            [name] => ]django]
        )
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [set `pagesize`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging) in the URL, like:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?pagesize=10&order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow
```