# Specific Response attributes

Tags: support, api

I want to get questions related to a specific tag with the body of those questions. I have figure out this API request:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/questions?site=stackoverflow&sort=votes&tagged=scalability&filter=withbody
```

I want to specify two more things:

- The number of returned questions, let's say 50 questions and
- I don't want some attributes returned by the API such as `owner`, Can I exclude this field?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of both [How to strip out certain fields...](http://stackapps.com/questions/4490/how-to-strip-out-certain-fields-from-the-stack-exchange-api-json-response) and [Limiting the number of items returned by a request](http://stackapps.com/questions/6186/limiting-the-number-of-items-returned-by-a-request).

Answer (score 2):

In order to get 50 questions for every request you need to pass `pagesize` parameter to your request URL. When you pass this parameter, you will need to pass `page` parameter to fetch the following pages.

In order to exclude some attributes from the default set, you can use the "Try It" part of the [documentation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions)  to create a filter for your specific purpose.

For example if you want to exclude owner from default filter you should be using `!9bDQ0*xgY` as your filter parameter.

In the end your request URL will look like http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow&pagesize=50&filter=!9bDQ0*xgY